# What happens to allocated memory when program quits in C

Tags: c

When I allocate memory from the heap and don't free it (by accident most likely!), are those memories freed up automatically by the os when the program quits?

Something like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int *m = malloc(100);
  printf("%p", m);
  return 0;
}
```

What happens to those 100 allocated bytes when the program quits the main?

Comment: Yes, the OS will clean up all of the process's memory on exit.

Comment: Yes, all memory segments of a process will be cleaned on exit, including the heap, which is where dynamic memory is allocated.

Comment: If it were possible for a careless program to "lose" memory -- if the operating system did *not* clean it up, perfectly reliably -- that would be a really horrible operating system!